# In a slurm job with multiple cores specified, how do I determine how many cores/CPUs are actually being used?

Tags: r, linux, slurm

I currently am running a job in R through Slurm. It is supposed to be able to take advantage of up to 64 cores. However, I have doubts that my program is actually using all 64 cores. Is there a way in Slurm to figure out how many cores were actually used? I tried `squeue` and `top` but cannot understand the output there. Is there an easy way to check? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [script](https://github.com/OleHolmNielsen/Slurm_tools/blob/master/jobs/psjob) will tell you how many processes are actually running and how heavily-used the CPUs are.

Comment: Thanks, does this script require admin privileges?

Comment: It might, depending on how the cluster is configured.